# Show & Hide stackpanel by clicking a button [Visual Studios 2019 for C++]

Tags: c++, hide, show, stackpanel, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to make it so that if I click the 'Start' button, then my application will change to another screen. So I figured I could probably do that by using the hiding/showing of stackpanels. Except, I'm not quite sure how to hide/show stackpanels. What is the proper way of implementing the show/hide for stackpanels in Visual Studios 2019 for C++?

I tried looking online for the correct way of hiding/showing for Visual C++ but haven't found anything. Most of what I found for C#, or outdated. The code below was one of my desperate attempts in getting this to work...

```
void myApp1::MainPage::ButtonPick_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Application::Current->hide();
}
```

This doesn't even compile because this isn't the correct way of hiding. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!